# Prometheus alert if the metric is never sent from an instance

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, monitor

I have instances which creates daily backups. And the metrics for this process are only created after first backup.

I want to get alerted if there is no backup for a day. I already have set this by checking if `latest_backup_age` is more than certain age (24h).

But I am facing problem when a new instance is created and it never creates a backup. I have `up` metric which is available for all the instances since the start of the process.

Current alert is like this

```
max by(env, region, cluster) latest_backup_age{job="my-pods",type="latest_backup"}) > 24
```

other metrics for the backup process are `total_backups` and `size_of_backups`
How do I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the PromQL:

```
sum by(instance) (total_backups{job="my-pods"}) == 0 and sum by(instance) (up{job="my-pods"} unless up{job="my-pods"} offset 1h)
```

The `instance` label should appear in each metric.

The explanation is as below:

1. Use the `up` metric to check if a new instance is created, promql segment after the `and` operator;
2. Use the `total_backups` metric to check if no backup is created and then alert.

These metrics should come from the same scrape job **my-pods**.